# Automating Workstation Setup

Tags: ros, environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been hacking at my kernel and breaking my system rather frequently lately setting up a USB3 ROS driver for a new 3D sensor. Aside from perhaps better recovery management, or using VMs, I'd like to find an programmatic way of bootstrapping a ROS environment for my workstation after every time I hose it. I've seen some people use chef cookbooks as means to automate a personalized suppresses, so I think that might be one direction to take.

Does anyone have working examples for quickly setting a Linux system?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216362/automating-workstation-setup/) by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1094 on 2015-08-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-08-23**:
Is your question relevant to ROS, Robot Operating System?

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2015-08-23**:
Pardon my first edit being too general, but my environment setup is ROS specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've played with using puppet to setup a basic ROS environment.

https://forge.puppetlabs.com/tfoote/ros
https://github.com/tfoote/puppet-ros

It was test a few months ago. It may need updating for more recent changes to some of the puppet module dependencies.

It's very basic at the moment and not fully parameterized, but is a good starting point for people.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, trying to run a bad kernel shouldn't make your system unbootable or otherwise unusable; assuming you're running grub and you keep a working kernel installed alongside your existing kernel, you should just be able to select a working kernel from the grub menu at startup. Ubuntu will generally set this up automatically for you.

If you're doing more invasive kernel work that does destroy your file system, you should ***really*** do that in a VM.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-08-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-08-24**:
+1: a borked kernel really shouldn't be an issue. If you trash all kinds of system libs in the process, recovery could be a bit more difficult though.

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2015-08-26**:
I was working on setting up intel's realsense sensor, some of it's USB3.0 attributes are hard to pipe to the VM software I had (like virtualbox), thus the need to use a real metal system for testing. Not to mention the VM overhead really slows things down when trying to profile performance.